# C64 loading screen

Tags: c#, animation

I have made a loading screen (splash screen) [just like the old C64](https://youtube.com/watch?v=7_3QteCI7Pk).  I have used a series of picture boxes and just change the coloured image using a timer and a case statement.

```
namespace c64
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            timer2.Start();
            timer3.Start();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int a = rnd.Next(1,8);
            int b = rnd.Next(1,8);
            int c = rnd.Next(1,8);
            int d= rnd.Next(1,8);
            int n= rnd.Next(1,8);
            int f= rnd.Next(1,8);
            int g= rnd.Next(1,8);
            int h = rnd.Next(1, 8);

            switch (a)
            {
                case 1: 
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox11.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                break;
                case 2:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                break;
                case 3:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                break;
                case 4:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                break;
                case 5:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                break;
                case 6:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                break;
                case 7:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                break;
                case 8:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                break;
            }

            switch (b)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox11.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    pictureBox11.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    pictureBox18.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    pictureBox18.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                    pictureBox12.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                    break;
            }

            switch (c)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox13.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    pictureBox13.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    pictureBox18.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox18.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox17.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                    break;
            }

            switch (d)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox14.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox17.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    pictureBox18.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    pictureBox18.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    pictureBox17.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    pictureBox18.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                    pictureBox18.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    pictureBox14.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;


                    break;
                case 6:
                    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                    pictureBox17.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                    break;
            }

            switch (n)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox15.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    pictureBox15.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                    break;
            }

            switch (f)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    pictureBox16.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                    break;
            }
            switch (g)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                    break;
            }
            switch (h)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
                    break;
            }

        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox21.Visible = true;

        }

        private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox21.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to get this effect?

Comment: I cant link a picture (or at least I dont know how to) but if you google C64 loading screen it will help (even select a video)

But the boxes are long line stripes across the page of one solid colour, that colour changes to another solid colour after a few ms. So I have roughly 21 of these boxes down the page and using timer I change them with a random number and a case statement (shown above) I have 8 case statements but its very untidy.

Comment: `timer2` and `timer3` control the visibility of `pictureBox21`. What is special about `pictureBox21`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's quite a lot of code duplication going on here... I would suggest refactoring the switch statements into a method.

I'm assuming there are 20 PictureBox objects and you want to randomize the shown image on each of those, because your provided code is a bit bizarre (e.g. `pictureBox11.Image` only ever gets assigned `Properties.Resources.image1` or `image3`, and sometimes there are multiple assignments for the same pictureBox inside a `case`)

```cs
namespace c64 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        private Random rng;
        private const Image[] Images = new Image[]{
            Properties.Resources.image1,
            Properties.Resources.image2,
            Properties.Resources.image3,
            Properties.Resources.image4,
            Properties.Resources.image5,
            Properties.Resources.image6,
            Properties.Resources.image7,
            Properties.Resources.image8
        };

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponents();
            rng = new Random();
        }

        private void RandomizeImage(PictureBox pictureBox) {
            int index = rng.Next(0, Images.Length - 1);
            pictureBox.Image = Images[index];
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox1);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox2);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox3);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox4);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox5);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox6);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox7);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox8);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox9);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox10);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox11);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox12);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox13);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox14);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox15);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox16);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox17);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox18);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox19);
            RandomizeImage(pictureBox20);
        }

        // rest of your code ...
    }
}
```

Of course, you could pack those pictureBoxX (X = 1 to 20) into their own array and iterate over them in a loop.